# Xamarin.Forms: View in C# vs. XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've inherited a Xamarin.Forms app which creates some of the views in C# rather than XAML.  Is there any clear advantage to moving these views to XAML?

Comment: There are a lot of opinions, especially in terms of maintainable & that is *very subjective* from developer to developer. One factor that a lot of people do not mention is parse/inflation "cost" of XAML. The "cost" is time (cpu cycles) and additional memory (transient objects that are created during the parse phase) and the GC cost of cleanup of those transient objects. The ease of using XAML at development time does have a cost and that cost is seen at runtime...

Comment: Using the Xamarin XAML compiler on your XAML massively helps, but not 100% of the XAML is compiled to static IL. Just like bindings, performance of a one-way  or both-way binding has a performance cost overhead compared to directly coding the object property updates...

Answer (score 2):

It is based on personal preference, but in general and to follow the standards putting in mind that other developers might work on that project in the future, it is recommended to use XAML.

XAML is easier to maintain and modify, helps with a clear separation of concerns between the UI and logic, [well suited for use with the popular MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) application architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm), and tooling friendly as there is a [XAML Previewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer) which allows you to see your Xamarin.Forms layouts rendered as you type.

**UPDATE**

You can drag-and-drop Xamarin.Forms controls from the toolbox to the XAML editing surface  as of Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 Preview 4.

Comment: You say that it helps with separation of concerns between the UI and the logic, but I don't see that -- the logic is in the VM.  (I for one have yet to get the XAML previewer to work.)  

That said, I do all my work in XAML, the question is whether it is worth converting existing (working) code from C# to XAML and I'm increasingly convinced it is not.   Thanks!